# DestinationAccessException while trying to access destination details using SAP Cloud SDK for JAVA

Tags: sap-cloud-sdk, sap-business-technology-platform

I am trying to retrieve the details of a destination using the APIs provided by SAP Cloud SDK for JAVA. I have added the following annotations to our Spring Boot application:

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.sap.cloud.sdk", "path to my package"}, excludeFilters = {@ComponentScan.Filter(type = CUSTOM, classes = TypeExcludeFilter.class)})
@ServletComponentScan({"com.sap.cloud.sdk", "path to my package"})
@SpringBootApplication()
public class ActionApplication {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ActionApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

The SpringBoot application **internally uses a JAVA library** developed by us. The code for fetching the destination details is present in this library:

```
    public static Destination getDestination() {
      Tenant consumerTenant = TenantAccessor.getCurrentTenant();
      return TenantAccessor.executeWithTenant(consumerTenant,
            () -> DestinationAccessor.getDestination(destinationName));
    }
```

I am able to get the destination details **EVERY TIME** I run my application **locally**.
However, when I run my application on cloud, after a **few successful attempts**, I get the following error:

```
"com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.thread.exception.ThreadContextExecutionException: com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.connectivity.exception.DestinationAccessException: Failed to get destination with name 'name_of_the_destination'."
```

To resolve the issue, I have to re-deploy my Spring Boot application.
Is anything wrong with the implementation? What I understand from the logs is, the threadcontext is not set correctly.

Comment: Can you motivate why you are getting the tenant and then setting it again? This seems unnecessary to me. Furthermore, do you have any additional log messages and/or a stack-trace? Otherwise it will be difficult to help. For example, is it possible that "after a few successful attempts" means something like after 5min precisely?

Comment: @AlexanderDümont
I have found a pattern. I tried to fetch the details of a destination which has authentication type of OAuth2ClientCredentials of a different sub account.

After that, whenever I try to fetch the details of any destination of my 1st subaccount, I keep getting the error in the description.

Comment: When I try to access the destination with OAuth2ClientCredentials authentication type, I get the following error

"com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.connectivity.exception.DestinationAccessException: Failed to read authentication token. The destination service responded with an error: 404 Not Found - {}"

The authTokens object received for the destination is:


"authTokens": [
        {
            "type": "",
            "value": "",
            **"error": "404 Not Found - {}"**,
            "expires_in": "0"
        }
    ]

Comment: After around 10 minutes, if I try to access the destination details of a different subaccount, I get the following error:
**com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.thread.exception.ThreadContextExecutionException: com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.connectivity.exception.DestinationAccessException: Failed to get destination with name 'name_of_the_destination'**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DefaultHttpDestination` should be used when building a destination instead of the `MockUtil` test class. The built destination should also be registered in a `DefaultDestinationLoader`, and this `DefaultDestinationLoader` should be prepended in the `DestinationAccessor`.